# ORACLE SQL where ending with takes time

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-like

we have table where we log the details whenever user logs in to the application.
we use below query to get the details which works fine

```
select username 
from table  
where username like 'abc%' 
order by timestamp desc
```

we get result

```
abcxyz
```

but when we put % at start of string it takes too much time and doesnt give any result.

```
select username 
from table  
where username like '%xyz' 
order by timestamp desc
```

or

```
select username 
from table  
where username like '%cx%' 
order by timestamp desc
```

Username column is indexed PFB details.
column_position:1
column_length:512
CHAR_length:512
Descend:ACS

Can someone explain this behavior and **how can I get the result for 2nd/3rd query**?

Comment: It will have to do a table span - see the explain plan

Comment: Put the explain plan here, as well as describe the indexes used on that table.

Comment: Here is  a [list of english words](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlist/english/oxford3000/)- Find all with the pattern 'ben%' and all with pattern '%ben'.

Comment: Here is the [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Britannica-32-Book-Set/dp/0852299613). Find all entries ending with `'%ben'`.

Answer (score 6):

Your observations would be completely expected if the `username` column had an index on it.  If it did have an index, then the following query could take advantage of that index when searching for matching user records:

```
select username from table where username like 'abc%' order by timestamp desc
```

The reason an index on `username` would help with the above `LIKE` expression is that a B-tree is built from left to right on the username.

On the other hand, an index on `username` would *not* be helpful for the following query:

```
select username from table where username like '%xyz' order by timestamp desc
```

In this case, the B-tree cannot help us to locate usernames *ending* in `xyz`.  This is the case because such matching records could appear anywhere in the tree.  Instead, a full table scan would probably be necessary.

For more information, you can try running explain on both of your queries.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, any way I can get results rapidly for this? 

Note: Indexing is enabled for this column

Comment: @rohitrk89 I'm not an expert in Oracle, and I don't know if it has a notion of a reverse index.  One thing you could do would be to store the string in reverse as well in a separate column and index that.  This would eat up some space, but then you could use `LIKE 'xyz%'` on the reversed string.

Comment: Yea, as a work around I can think of that but before going for that I'll look for solution to this only.

Comment: I gave you an upvote.  Or maybe you could open a new question; this one has been up for a while already.

Comment: Yea, Thanks for your help so far but looking a way to I get a result faster on existing data without workaround.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it should be LIKE 'zyx%' on the reversed column

Answer (score 0):

The first example fetches all usernames that START with "abc", and the rest can be anything.

The second one selects all usernames that start with ANYTHING, so it has to perform full table scan (whether there's an index on USERNAME column or not). Why does it not return anything? Well, you have the data, we don't. From what you wrote, no username ends with lowercase xyz.

The same goes for the third SELECT.

If you frequently perform such a queries, consider using Oracle Text.